# Step tracker and step detector hardware is not working in Motorola android device

Tags: android, performance, android-sensors, motorola, sensormanager

The step tracker and step detector is not working in Motorola's G.

I went through the code which checks device API version should be greater than Kitkat and checks two Sensors' availability and they are available:-

```
        packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER);
packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_DETECTOR);
```

Both the System API features return false.

But in the device specification I can see that Accelerometer is available.

Can you please tell me whether this is a device configuration issue?

Answer (score 1):

The Step Counter and Step Detector sensor are not the same as the Accelerometer sensor, although presumably they use it. They are pseudo-sensors running on a so-called sensor co-processor, i.e. algorithms calculating steps from data provided by other sensors. As they work on a hardware level, they require less battery. If the Accelerometer sensor is integrated, it does not necessarily mean that there is also a Step Detector and a Step Counter. So if the result is false, those don't seem to be implemented.

You can implement your own step-detection algorithm using the acceleration data. That's what I did, but I wouldn't recommend this because the battery use is extremely high as you have to keep the system awake.